# Collapsible Tree View - Collapsing the intended subtree instead of all subtrees of the same level

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, collapsable

I am currently working on implementing a collapsible tree view for product categorization. The tree view is functional, but I'm facing an issue with the collapsing behavior. Instead of collapsing only the targeted item, it collapses all the items at the same level.

We're using Vue 2.7.3 in combination with BootstrapVue for the collapsable subtrees. I have set up a GitHub repository with a reproduction: https://github.com/bugreproducer/vue2.7-collapsable-tree

In the repo above, when clicking on any toggle button, it collapses or expands all the items at the same level, instead of toggling only the intended item. I only want to hide / show the underlying children.

I'm seeking guidance on how to modify the code to achieve the desired behavior of collapsing only the targeted items when the toggle button is clicked.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Instead of collapsing only the targeted item, it collapses all the items at the same level. I'm seeking assistance to resolve this bug in my implementation.